# Why "bad argument" error in fs.write

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok.
So I'm trying to read a number from one file, which represents a counter, do some looping and each time write to a second file and then stop whenever I feel like and write the new value of the counter to the same first file.

```
var textPath = "/kolodvori.txt";
var countPath = "/dijestao.txt";
var buffer = new Buffer(0);

fs.readFile(countPath, function (err,data){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {      
        console.log(data);
        i = data;

        var stream2 = fs.createWriteStream(textPath, {flags: 'a'});

        stream2.once('open', function (fd){ 
            fs.open(countPath,'w', function (fd2){
                getPageHtml(defHost, firstNewPath, i, function (html,count,callback){

                    if (count%10==0) console.log(count);

                    ++count;
                    i = new Buffer(count.toString());

                    //console.log('i:' + i);
                    fs.write(fd2, i, 0, i.length, null, function (err,len,buff){ console.log(err); });

                    var newPath = defPath.replace(/xxxKOLO1xxx/gi, count);

                    getPageHtml(defHost, newPath, count, callback);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

After all my hard work I'm rewarded with a

```
fs.js:513
binding.write(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, wrapper);
        ^
TypeError: Bad argument
     at Object.fs.write (fs.js:513:11)
```

What does "bad argument" even mean in this context?
Has it something to do with me having 2 ways of reading and then writing to the same file?

Comment: You may have wrong callback function? Change `function (fd2)` to `function (err, fd2)`

Comment: Nope, works the same after the fix

Comment: :-) Here is the document: The callback gets two arguments `(err, fd)`. http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback . Good luck kungi.

Comment: So sorry man, yeah, that fixed the problem <3

Answer (score 2):

Use `path.join(__dirname, "./kolodvori.txt"`) and `path.join(__dirname, "./dijestao.txt")` instead.

Using `/` means relative to the `root`, and you want to be relative to your script's directory.

Remember to do `var path = require("path");` at the top.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was the second thing I had to fix. Unfortunately its not relevant to the current problem

Comment: What are you getting now?

Comment: The same. The problem is not in the position of the files

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and ended up using writeFile.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback